# It's possible create a listener to a div class with puppeteer?

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer, listener

Hell, it's possible create a listener to a div class?
i see some listener but for events, in website were i'm trying to get a list about innerText, i manage to get the value in first time, but i cant get the values again when they are add, i check in console when they add new values do not show any event, i only have a div class.

this is how i'm trying to get the values in first time:

```
 const numbers = await entryHall.$$eval('.lobby-table', el => el.map(roleta => roleta.innerText))
    const values = Array.from(numbers.values())
    console.log(values)
```

[the website has 27 of this box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJuHX.png)
i manage to get the values in first time, but i dont know how to continue getting the new values
[values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLp2E.png)
[this is my .lobby-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZliZ.jpg)

i search a lot, but i only find for events, it's possible create an listener for a div class?

Comment: What do you mean by a listener for a div class? Are you looking for a MutationObserver? Please add more details about the site you're working with, the data you want from it, and when you want to get the data. Thanks.

Comment: hi i add more details about what i'm trying to do, maybe i dont know how to see the events using "F12"